# Is there a reason why I need to use stripslashes for user submitted data?

Tags: php, stripslashes

What do people use stripslashes for and is it typically used in conjunction with addslashes? Why should I strip or add slashes to a string that's submitted by a user?

Comment: because you probably escaped it when u received it from the user

Comment: You shouldn't. It's a workaround to undo the magic_quotes workaround.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should *always* sanitize the user's input. But not with `addslashes()`... If you want to compose a query with the user's input, use the proper database escaping mechanism (look into [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) and [PDO prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)).

The reason for sanitizing user input is security. Read about [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and [cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), which are the two most common security problems arising from un-sanitized input.

Comment: So what is the proper way to sanitize statements with stripslashes and why do I need to strip the slashes?

Comment: `stripslashes()` does not sanitize statements... you don't need to use `stripslashes()` unless you have a string containing `\'` sequences and you want to remove the backslashes.

Comment: I see. So when inserting something into the database I sanitize with mysql_real_escape_string then when I retrieve and display I use stripslashes?

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string()` ensures that the string is properly passed to the query, thus not getting any extra slashes. You don't need to use `stripslashes()` when getting the string back. Do however use [`htmlspecialhars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) when displaying *any* text to the user that you don't compose yourself (such as those obtained from the database or from other users).

Comment: @Cfarm: no. the slashes will NOT be stored in the database. That's the whole point of escape characters. As soon as they pass through something that understands them, one level of escaping is removed.